# PHP failing checking variables

Tags: php

I have a problem with my PHP script, which checks 3 variables (code below):

`$auth` (The mail author)
`$subj` (The mail subject)
`$text` (The mail message)

FORM:
(NOTE: I used the "GET" method because for some strange reason the "POST" method didn't work)

```
                <div id="contact_form">
                        <form method="get" name="contact" action="home.php">
                                <input type="hidden"
                                       name="method"
                                       value="send"/>
                                E-Mail:<br/>
                                <input type="text"
                                       id="author" 
                                       name="author" 
                                       class="require input_field"
                                       value=""/>

                                <br/>
                                Subject:<br/>
                                <input type="text"
                                       id="subject" 
                                       name="subject" 
                                       class="require input_field"
                                       value=""/>

                                <br/>
                                Message:<br/>
                                <textarea id="text"
                                      name="text"
                                      rows="0"
                                      cols="0"
                                      class="required"
                                      value=""></textarea>

                                <br/>
                                <input type="submit"
                                       class="submit_btn"
                                       name="submit"
                                       id="submit"
                                       value="Submit" />
            </form>
        </div>
```

The form works just fine now.

PHP:

```
<?php // ||HOME.PHP||
$method = $_GET['method'];
$auth = $_GET['author'];
$subj = $_GET['subject'];
$text = $_GET['text'];
$recv = "mymail@stuff.com";


function redirect($location) {
        if($location == "true") {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=true");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=false");
        }
}

//...
//Other methods...
//...

//METHOD SEND
if($method == "send") {


    //HERE IS THE PROBLEM
    //These are apparently not working
    //If i leave the form blank and submit it
    //these won't redirect to "false" (mail not sent),
    //and the script will just continue, send the empty mail
    //and redirect to "true" (mail sent)

    if(empty($auth)) { redirect(""); }
    if(empty($subj)) { redirect(""); }
    if(empty($text)) { redirect(""); }

    if(!strstr($auth, '@')) { redirect(""); }
    if(!strstr($auth, '.')) { redirect(""); }

    if(strlen($auth) < 5) { redirect(""); }
    if(strlen($subj) < 4) { redirect(""); }
    if(strlen($text) < 4) { redirect(""); }

    //From here it should work just fine
    //As i'm not sure the "RESULT" method (below) is working fine, i
    //posted it too.




    $auth =  "From: " . $auth;

    mail($recv,$subj,$text,$auth);
    redirect("true");

    require("template/footer.html");

    exit(0);
}

//METHOD RESULT
if($method == "result") {

    $status = $_GET['status'];

    if($status == "true") {
        echo "mail sent";
    } else {
        echo "mail not sent";
    }
    ?>

    <script language="javascript">
        setTimeout("location.href = 'http://adteam.altervista.org/home.php';", 5000);
    </script>

    <?php

    exit(0);
} ?>
```

The problem is explained in the PHP code (in the comments below the "SEND" method).

Do you guys have any suggestion?

Comment: do a `var_dump($_GET)` and see what the value of `method` is

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php and look at the enable post data reading flag. Perhaps that would help for the post issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the script execution after you've set the redirect headers. Otherwise it will just continue to sending the mail and set new redirect headers before any headers are sent to the browser.

```
function redirect($location) {
    if($location) {
        header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=true");
    } else {
        header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=false");
    }

    die();
}
```

Note that `if( $location == "true" )` is kind of an anti-pattern; it's better to use boolean `true` and `false` instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Should be easy. Your saying that "" is false. But it ain't: because "" is true, but empty which is true. false is not set or specified false. So you should do:

```
function redirect($location) {
        if($location) {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=true");
            exit();
        } else {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=false");
            exit();
        }
}


And use: redirect(true) / redirect(false);
```

Comment: Your answer probably didnt work for him and he thinks this is reddit?

Comment: You were downvoted before you added the `exit()`s which solves the *actual* problem. String comparison is cumbersome, but `"" == "true"` is *not* boolean `true`. That part should work correctly even as it was.

Answer (score 0):

A string will always evaluate to true, even if it is empty. That's precisely the reason why we check strings using empty() as opposed to isset(). A few more things:

1. You should be using POST to submit the email.
2. You should probably check if the form was actually submitted before validating the input.
3. You should create and display specific error messages telling the user what required fields they did not complete.
4. You should run some careful validation routines on the input to avoid having your email form used to send spam and malware.

Comment: Note that at no point a string is being compared to boolean `true`, so your point is moot.

Comment: @juhana lol that's true, I didn't notice that the OP wrapped true in quotes.. However the OP is using == as opposed to === so it's not a strict type comparison. Either way, it's the wrong way to go about it and the OP was most likely unaware that empty strings evaluate as true.

Comment: I know my code is really bad, but I'm still learning PHP.
Thank you for your tips :)

Comment: No Problem! If you need more help just let me know.

Answer (score -1):

Simply add `exit` in false branch:

```
function redirect($location) {
        if($location == "true") {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=true");
        } else {
            header("Location: http://mysite.com/home.php?method=result&status=false");
            exit(0); //simply add it here
        }
}
```

`header` function does not stop further execution by itself and you must stop doing anything else if do not want to send an email when something is wrong.

Actually, you may simply add exit after if statement.